# How to start and end an email politely?

Tags: politeness, email

I'm trying to write an email to professor because I found a mistake on his book. Should I start the email with just "Dear professor, There seems to be some problems in ..." and end the email as "best wishes" or "with best regards" or "yours sincerely"?

Comment: I will say that writing a polite email is tricky, since a sort of telegraphic style is usually expected, so it often seems that the "usual niceties" are a bit pompous.  But leaving them off seems Spartan and rude.  But in the case where this is a "cold" email to someone with whom you've not previously corresponded, it's probably best to err or the side of formality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in Britain you would write "Dear Professor NN" (with his or her name) at the beginning, and "Yours sincerely" followed by your name at the end. But I would certainly not begin the body of the message with "There seems to be some problem...". Better to start off with "I was reading your excellent book XYZ and noticed..." or something like that.